# NODEJS, PUG, EXPRESS - Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: node.js, function, api, for-loop, pug

I have an API that i tweaked to make 2 calls to my DB and pull down information .. I can see the results in my console log so i know it is working

The next part is when it renders the view i need to show the results in two places

Here is the code for the API that makes 2 calls to the DB

```
function apples(req, res, next) {
  sql.connect(config, function () {
    var request = new sql.Request();
    request.query("select price from table WHERE fruit = 'apples'", function(err, recordsetapples) {
      var arrayLength = recordsetapples.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        console.log(recordsetapples[i]["price"]);
      };
      res.render('index', { resultsapples: recordsetapples });
        return next();
    });
  });
};

function pear(req, res, next) {
  sql.connect(config, function () {
    var request = new sql.Request();
    request.query("select price from table WHERE fruit = 'pear'", function(err, recordsetpear) {
      var arrayLength = recordsetpear.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        console.log(recordsetpear[i]["price"]);
      };
      res.render('index', { resultspear: recordsetpear });
        next();
    });
  });
};



app.get('/fruit', apples, pear);
```

So after that runs I can see the price print in console log .. Then i see this error

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

What i expect to see if the price appear ... To get that info i have this code

```
      tr
        th.hidden-phone Fruit
        th.hidden-phone Price
      tr
      each val in resultsapples
        td.hidden-phone Apples
        td.hidden-phone !{val.price}
      tr
      each val in resultspear
        td.hidden-phone Pears
        td.hidden-phone !{val.price}
```

Comment: Whilst not explicitly related to your problem, you don't check for the error object in your sql code. You should update this to make sure there is no error and use a callback or the like to determine if there was an error or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your view expects both lists at the same time but you attempt to render the view twice with each list separately, which means in either scenario one list in the view will be `undefined`.

Even if you were to fix this, this approach won't work anyway because after the first `res.render` the HTTP response will end and return to the client. Ideally you would want to make one trip to the DB for both resultsets and then render the view e.g.

```
sql.connect(config, () => {
  const request = new sql.Request();
  request.query("select price from table WHERE fruit = 'apples' OR fruit = 'pear'", (err, result) => {
    res.render('index', { 
      resultsapples: result.recordsets[0], 
      resultspear: result.recordsets[1]
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: So this has gotten rid of the error and it is now showing the index page but still nothing showing from the index page the the price piece

Comment: @zoomer looks like there is a typo in my code, `resultapples` should be `resultsapples` & `resultpears` should be `resultspears`

Answer (score 0):

As James mentioned your callbacks are async so you're trying to render the view twice. You also need some error handling in your sql functions

```
function apples(cb) {
  sql.connect(config, function () {
    var request = new sql.Request();
    request.query("select price from table WHERE fruit = 'apples'", function(err, recordsetapples) {
      if(err) {
          return cb(err);
      }
      var arrayLength = recordsetapples.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        console.log(recordsetapples[i]["price"]);
      };
      cb(false, recordsetapples);
    });
  });
};

function pear(cb) {
  sql.connect(config, function () {
    var request = new sql.Request();
    request.query("select price from table WHERE fruit = 'pear'", function(err, recordsetpear) {

      if(err){
          return cb(err)
      }
      var arrayLength = recordsetpear.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        console.log(recordsetpear[i]["price"]);
      };
      cb(false,recordsetpear);
    });
  });
};



app.get('/fruit', (req,res) => {
     apples((appleerr,appleset) => {
         if(appleerr){
          //render error page
         } else {
           pear((pearerr, pearset) => {
              if(pearerr) {
                  //render error page
              } else {
                return res.render('index', { 
                   resultapples: appleset, 
                   resultpears: pearset
                });
              }
           })
         }
     });
});
```

Now for the record, I'm not a fan of nesting the callbacks like this so I would actually recommend you look at Promises and/or `async/await` but I'm not sure on your coding level so I didn't want to throw too many concepts at you at once.

Also whereas James has merged your SQL statements into one (which is probably the right approach for you) I kept them separate not knowing if you were reusing these individual pieces of code elsewhere and as such didn't want to combine them.

If you are interested in the promise implementation it might look as follows:

```
function apples() {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      sql.connect(config, function () {
        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.query("select price from table WHERE fruit = 'apples'", function(err, recordsetapples) {
          if(err) {
              reject(err);
          }
          var arrayLength = recordsetapples.length;
          for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            console.log(recordsetapples[i]["price"]);
          };
          resolve(recordsetapples);
        });
      });
    };

    function pear() {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {

      sql.connect(config, function () {
        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.query("select price from table WHERE fruit = 'pear'", function(err, recordsetpear) {

          if(err){
              reject(err)
          }
          var arrayLength = recordsetpear.length;
          for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            console.log(recordsetpear[i]["price"]);
          };
          resolve(recordsetpear);
        });
      });
       });
    };



    app.get('/fruit', (req,res) => {
         var applePromise = apples()
         var pearsPromise = applePromise.then((appleSet)) {
             return pear()
         }

         Promise.all([applePromise,pearsPromise]).then((([appleSet,pearSet]) => {
             res.render('index', { 
                resultapples: appleSet, 
                resultpear: pearSet
            });
         }).catch((err) => {
             //render error
         })
    });
```

Comment: Even if both requests need to be separate, I'd still argue the case for at least using a single DB connection. Also, there is a lot of duplication in the code I'd look to get rid of.

Comment: Yes that's a valid point, or depending on the library making use of a pool